# What do these line of codes mean?These are codes in matlab

Tags: image, matlab

When I run these codes, they show number of green dots on a white background. I can identify the code for white background, but from where do these green dots come as they have not provided any color assignment?

```
a(1:400,1:400,1:3)=255;
l(1:200,1:2)=0;
d(1:200,1)=1000;
sd(1,1)=0;
for g=1:200     
    l(g,1:2)=randint(1,2,[20 380]);
    for i=1:360
        for r=0:3
            x=l(g,1)+r*cos(i);
            y=l(g,2)+r*sin(i);
            x=round(x);
            y=round(y);
            a(x,y,1:3)=255;
            a(x,y,1:2:3)=0;
        end
    end
    imshow(a)
end
```

Comment: This would probably be better received over at Math.StackExchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the line

```
a(x,y,1:2:3)=0;
```

#### Explanation:

`a` is a 3D array 400-by-400-by-3: the third dimension is of size 3 for RGB values. The command [`1:2:3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) creates a vecotr, starting from `1` till `3` with jumps of `2` resulting with `[1 3]` vector. As a result `a(x,y,1:2:3)=0` sets the red and blue channels (first and third resp.) to zero leaving only the green channel (second one) set to 255 resulting with a green pixel.

Comment: Superb explanation. Thanks a lot. I'll be glad if you can refer me some books or website reference as I want to study more about color channels in matlab.

Comment: Why to calculate x and y using sine and cos? It could be any random location I guess?

Comment: @anurag I did not try to understand what this code is doing, only explaining the green outputs you observed.